# Is there any file number limitation when you select multiple files with wxFileDialog?

Tags: python, wxpython

I tried with wxFileDialog to select multiple files when using wxPython. But I always get "Common dialog failed with error code 3003" when I selected more than 2700 files at one time. If I select only 2000 files it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's a limitation of the underlying Windows common file dialog, which (allegedly) has a 65535-character buffer for the list of filenames.

See for instance [Shameful limitation: File Open dialog cannot return more than 1000 files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/shameful-limitation-file-open-dialog-cannot-return/bfff43fc-0da5-48d6-8703-dc0eac3c7581).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It does a lot help/